# Adicionar hyperlink em MessageBox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

É possível personalizar o `MessageBox.Show("http://www.google.com/");` para que esse link seja um hyperlink e quando eu clique abra num navegador?

A única possibilidade realmente seria criar um formulário novo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem duas opções:

1. Criar um *form* novo para simular um `MessageBox`

   Neste caso, só é necessário criar um *form* normal, adicionar um `label` para 
   ser o link e adicionar o evento de *click* nele.

   Ex.:

   ```
   private void labelLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Label lb = (Label)sender;
       Process.Start(lb.Text);
   }
   ```
2. Usar um dos botões do `MessageBox` para abrir o link.

   ```
   var result = MessageBox.Show("Clique em ok para ir para http://www.google.com");

   if(result == DialogResult.Ok)
   {
       Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Usei assim >>**

```
var tituloDaMensagem = "Aviso do Robô - COD. 0025";
var mensagem = $ "Erro ao verificar o laçamento. Clique em ok para ver como solucionar o erro";
MessageBoxButton buttons = MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel;
MessageBoxResult result;
result = MessageBox.Show(mensagem, tituloDaMensagem, buttons, MessageBoxImage.Error);
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes) {
  Process.Start("http://www.suaurl.com");
}
```